# Rcpp Compile Attributes creates void argument

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, cran

In developing the R package [BayesMallows](https://github.com/ocbe-uio/BayesMallows) which uses [Rcpp](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html) as well as [unit testing with Catch via the testthat package](https://testthat.r-lib.org/reference/use_catch.html). Recently we have noticed an issue which creates an LTO issue on CRAN. Here is a minimal example.

First I create an Rcpp package.

```r
Rcpp::Rcpp.package.skeleton()
setwd("anRpackage/")
```

Then add unit testing with Catch:

```r
testthat::use_catch()
```

Then modify DESCRIPTION to the following:

```
Package: anRpackage
Type: Package
Title: What the Package Does in One 'Title Case' Line
Version: 1.0
Date: 2023-08-29
Author: Your Name
Maintainer: Your Name <your@email.com>
Description: One paragraph description of what the package does as one or more full sentences.
License: GPL (>= 2)
Imports: Rcpp (>= 1.0.11)
LinkingTo: Rcpp, testthat
Suggests: xml2
```

If I at this point run `Rcpp::compileAttributes()`, the following entry in `src/RcppExports.cpp` is generated:

```cpp
RcppExport SEXP run_testthat_tests(void *);
```

This line causes an issue on CRAN, in particular "LTO build failure: type violates the C++ One Definition Rule". We have fixed the issue manually for now, by modifying the line to what it was previously, namely

```cpp
RcppExport SEXP run_testthat_tests(SEXP);
```

However, whenever I rerun `Rcpp::compileAttributes()`, this `SEXP` argument is changed to `void *`. I'm on R4.3.1, and I experience this both on Mac and on Windows. I run testthat version 3.1.10 and Rcpp version 1.0.11.

On Mac, the command `gcc --version` returns the following:

```bash
Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

Any suggestions on what is going on, and how to fix it?

Comment: Related GH issue, for the record: https://github.com/r-lib/testthat/issues/1230

Comment: Yes this looks like a bad interaction between `testthat` and `catch`. (Also your first line in `NAMESPACE` already covers this so adding the fourth does nothing.)

Comment: I overlooked the `NAMESPACE` duplication. Question updated.

Comment: Inaki put a fix in, please see https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/pull/1274

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by an incorrect interface creation from base R. It has been reported there in the R Bugzilla, and a fix has been added to Rcpp itself in [pull request #1274](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/pull/1274).

Following the usual complete reverse-dependency testing (which takes a moment on an old machine given the over 2700 packages to be tested), this has now been merged, and a new development release 1.0.11.2 has been cut which can installed (as usual) from the [Rcpp drat](https://rcppcore.github.io/drat/), or from [r-universe](https://rcppcore.r-universe.dev/Rcpp) (starting from in about an hour once its scheduled builds catch up) or of course [from the github repo](https://github.com/rcppcore/rcpp).

Special thanks to Iñaki for the fix, and thanks for the bug report.